# How to map column of type "int unsigned" to "long" with entity framework 2.2.2 and MySql connector

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I have a table in MySql database where one of the columns is of type `int unsigned` and represents Unix timestamps. I am using Entity Framework Core 2.2.2 with official MySql connector `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore`, NuGet version 8.0.15.

In our entity model we are trying to represent this field with a property `EndTariffPlan` of type `long?` with this logic in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
{
    entity.Property(e => e.EndTariffPlan)
        .HasColumnName("endTariffPlan")
        .HasColumnType("int(11) unsigned");
}
```

When the timestamp is bigger than `Int32.MaxValue`, queries to a database like `_dbContext.User.FirstOrDefault()` are failing with the exception

`System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.`

```
An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.    System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
   at System.Convert.ThrowInt32OverflowException()
   at System.UInt32.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i)
   at lambda_method(Closure , DbDataReader )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.TypedRelationalValueBufferFactory.Create(DbDataReader dataReader)
```

I also tried to add `CastingConverter` for this property:

```
var intToLongConverter = new CastingConverter<long, int>();
entity.Property(e => e.EndTariffPlan)
    .HasColumnName("endTariffPlan")
    .HasColumnType("int(11) unsigned")
    .HasConversion(intToLongConverter);
```

but result is exactly the same.

The same code worked with Entity Framework Core 2.0 and `MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore` 8.0.12.

How to perform such type of mapping with new versions of Entity Framework Core and MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore? Maybe there is a workaround for this?

Comment: If it represents Unix timestamps, wouldn't you rather map it to `DateTime`?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn with `DateTime`  or `DateTimeOffset` type for a property exception is 

`InvalidOperationException: The property User.EndTariffPlan is of type DateTime which is not supported by current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the [NotMapped]attribute or by using EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore OnModelCreating`

I also tried to add a value conversion to from long to DateTimeOffset, but it results in the same `System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32` exception.